# How to disable progress feature in windows 7 or 8?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, firefox, taskbar

When you download something say a file in Mozilla Firefox browser a green bar starts occupying the browser's icon on task-bar that shows the overall progress of download(s) going on .But, I want to disable this feature. How can I disable the feature ? Also give a way to enable it too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't allow me be the bearer of bad news.

It seems the progress bar overlay is implemented by Firefox, so I doubt if you can disable on Windows. There seems to be no way to disable it on Firefox currently.

However, according to an answer given to this same issue, a possible solution may be to edit certain files in the Firefox Download API that makes it think the download is complete.

> You may want to read this article: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/969790#answer-477588